# How can I forcefully open app if app is installed on click the link

Tags: android, redirect, deep-linking, intentfilter

I'm writing this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file
If my app is installed on the device and click on the link open the app directly with a popup dialog.

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />

            <data android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the device setting "open supported links" by default "Ask every time" so how can I change this setting programmatically when the app install the first time like Amazon.

I don't want to open this dialog
[This is my emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQUT5.png)

Comment: Are you using Firebase Dynamic Links for Deep Linking?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please add your answer?

Answer (score 0):

there is no any solution for forcing android open your app whit no dialog!,
but in your screenshot there is a button < always >
when user once click on this button , for further launching dialog wont appear and your app will be opened (whitout dialog)

Comment: Are know how to change "Open support links" selection?